# Convert array output to table using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm exporting certificates from Windows CA which is an array which has data in below format. I want to convert into table. Any idea?

From:

```
$a=@(
'a=all
 b=call
',
'a=all
 b=ll'
)
```

Current output:

```
a=all
b=call

a=all
b=ll
```

Desired output:

```
a     b
all   call
all   ll
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an array of multiline strings. For the desired output you need an array of objects:

```
$a = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'a' = 'all'
        'b' = 'call'
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'a' = 'all'
        'b' = 'll'
    }
)
```

If your input data is actually a list of multiline strings with lines of the form `key=value` you can transform those into custom objects like this:

```
$a = @(
'a=all
b=call',
'a=all
b=ll'
)

$a | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]($_ | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}
```

`ConvertFrom-StringData` converts a string with one or more lines of `key=value` pairs into a hashtable, which can then be cast into a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also Create an empty Array and then just add values using [PsCustomObject]

```
$Table = @()
$Table += [Pscustomobject]@{a = "all"; b = "call"}
$Table += [Pscustomobject]@{a = "all"; b = "ll"}
```

Comment: Appending to an array is a slow operation and should be avoided where possible.